# Comparing grades relatively and absolutely

Tags: list, statistics, compare, ranking

Assuming we have 3 automated graders (G1, G2, and G3) that we want to compare against a human grader. The graders are asked to grade three assignments and assign them a grade from 1 - 5.
The results are shown in the following table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5BGz.png)

We need to compare two things: relative ranking and absolute grades. The objective is to measure which automated grader produced grades that are most aligned with the human grader in terms of ranking and absolute grades. What statistical tests are most appropriate for this type of analysis.

T-test, I expected p values.

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to StackOverflow. A couple of points:

Comment: 1. your question doesn't list a programming language, nor does it include any code. That might be a problem on a programming site

Comment: 2. pictures of data aren't useful. Include the data itself, not pictures of it

Comment: 3. Is this a homework problem?